# Fourier transform involving square of Dirac delta function

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

What does this expression involving a squared Dirac $\delta$-function evaluate to?
$$
\int\int\int\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\delta^2(\vec r_1  - \vec r_2) \exp  \left[ - \mathrm{i}  \! \left(  \vec r_1 \!\cdot\! \vec q_1 \! + \!\vec r_2 \!\cdot \!\vec q_2 \right)  \right] \,   d \vec r_1 \,  d \vec r_2
$$

Comment: Any reason why this should be defined?

Comment: Normally, there is no decent way to define the product of arbitrary distributions (this is a famous theorem of Schwartz). However, Colombeau defined a suitable notion of product (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombeau_algebra) in a weaker setting, but I do not know if this can give an acceptable meaning to your integral...

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4627326/2513

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure that your $\delta^2(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2)$ really means the product $\delta(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2)\delta(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2)$ ? Then this integral makes no sense, but since you are referring to rank-two vectors (in view of the four-fold integral), it is likely that the intended meaning of $\delta^2$ is 
$$\delta^2(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2)=\delta(x_1-x_2)\delta(y_1-y_2),$$
 where $\vec{r}_n=(x_n,y_n)$. (This notation $\delta^n(\vec{r})$ is the usual way to write a delta function of a rank-$n$ vector $\vec{r}$, you might want to check your source to see if this is indeed intended.) Assuming that this is the intended notation, then your integral evaluates to $(2\pi)^2\delta(\vec{q}_1+\vec{q}_2)$.